# Is prefix a reserved keyword in mysql

Tags: mysql, dbunit

Is 'prefix' a reserved keyword in 'mysql', since I get the following error when I try to populate sample data using dbunit for a table containing column called `'prefix'`

Embedded error: user.PREFIX - (Non-uppercase input column: prefix) in ColumnNameToIndexes cache map. Note that the map's column names are NOT case sensitive.

Comment: prefix is not a reserved keyword in mysql, and the error message is specifically on dbunit instead of mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL reserved keywords are documented here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html

Apart from the fact that `PREFIX` is not in the list, you should note that MySQL errors don't look like this. To begin with, they always start with a numeric error code.

Are you by chance calling as lowercase `prefix` a column you've defined as uppercase `PREFIX`?